# Question about horizontal shifts in function transformations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I had a question about $y=\sqrt{-x+4}$. I missed it, because I first reflected about the y axis then moved the graph left 4. That was wrong, because apparently I need to factor out a -1 to get $y=\sqrt{-1(x-4)}$, and the graph should actually shift to the right, instead of left.

Then I had $y=-2(3)^{5-x}$. Following the logic of the previous problem, I would factor out a -1 to get $y=-2(3)^{-1(-5+x)}$, and shift the graph to the right. However, this is not correct, and this graph is shifted to the left.

I don't get the difference between these two problems, when they both have a negative x, and a positive integer. Why does one shift to the left, and one shifts to the right?

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: In both the cases, the graph indeed shifts right. (Not left in the latter case).

Comment: InanimateBeing, I now see that you are correct, and I'm not sure why I thought the second one was shifted left. I think I just needed a break from this topic, and perhaps more practice and thought about the order of operations.

Comment: In your second example $y=-2(3)^{5-x}$ think of it as replacing $y=2(3)^{5-x}$ with $-y=2(3)^{5-x}$. When $y$ is replaced with $-y$ the graph is reflected about the $x$-axis. All examples of graphing $y=-f(x)$ should be conceptualized as replacing $y$ with $-y$. Then it is clear that the logic is the same as when replacing $x$ with $-x$. Otherwise one is left with a semblance of inconsistency in the operations.

Comment: Welcome to this site! If the issue has been resolved, do consider [accepting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) ✔ and upvoting ▲ answers: this signals resolution, prevents the page from being bumped, scores points, and influences the site's search results, cleanup activities, and other behind-the-scenes processes.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do the graph transformation for both (starting from step $0$):
$$y=\sqrt x$$

|  |
| --- |
| [image: 1] |

$$y=\sqrt {-x}$$

|  |
| --- |
| [image: 2] |

$$y=\sqrt {-(x-4)}$$

|  |
| --- |
| [image: 3] |

---

$$y=K^x$$

|  |
| --- |
| [image: 4] |

$$y=-K^x$$

|  |
| --- |
| [image: 5] |

$$y=-K^{-x}$$

|  |
| --- |
| [image: 6] |

$$y=-K^{-(x-5)}$$

|  |
| --- |
| [image: 7] |

---

In case you ever have confusion, you may refer [this link on Graph Transformation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4515138/graph-transformation)