# Sketch the graph of $ y=(x+1)^{2}-3 $ show the curve intersects the x and y axis

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question**:

> Sketch the graph of $ y=(x+1)^{2}-3 $ show the curve intersects the $x$ and $y$ axis

So for the $y$-intercept I calculated this to be $-2$.

However, for the $x$-intercept do you compute using completing the square or expanding the brackets and then deriving the quadratic formula?

Comment: Why must you use a _formula_ to find the $x$-intercepts?  Calculate them the same way you calculated the $y$-intercept.

Comment: For x interceps set $y=0$ and solve. In your case that can be done with a few manipulations, no need for quadratic equation [the square is almost already completed.]

Comment: I had assumed due to the way function and how completing the square is set out you use it+ i try to go for the fastest method possible on my calculator @AndrewChin

Comment: So when y=0   0=(x+1)^2-3? @coffeemath and then x is either + or negative root 3 or -1 positive or neagtive root 3?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4515138/977780)

Comment: AMN--- not quite. One gets $(x+1)^2=3$ so that $x+1=\pm \sqrt{3}.$ Finally subtract $1$ from eacjh side get $x=-1 \pm \sqrt{3}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also use [Graph Transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4515138/graph-transformation).
The best thing about it is that if you know the basic graph, you may easily arrive at your desired graph. 
Here's how you'd do it:
$$y=x^2$$
[image]
$$y=(x+1)^2$$
[image]
$$y=(x+1)^2-3$$
[image]

To get the value of intercepts, put $x=0$ and then $y=0$ in your equation to get respectively the values for x-intercept and y-intercept.

$x$-intercept:
$y=(0+1)^2-3=-2$
$x$-intercept$=(0,-2)$

$y$-intercept:
$0=(x+1)^2-3$
$\pm\sqrt3=x+1$
$\Rightarrow x=-1\pm\sqrt3$
$y$-intercept$=(-1+\sqrt3)$ and $(-1-\sqrt3)$

Comment: $+1$ . Nice application of $3$ elementary transformations.

Comment: @SouravGhosh thank you, luckily it came handy [here too](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4516287/question-about-horizontal-shifts-in-function-transformations/4516306#4516306). :-)

Answer (score 0):

The curve is shown in the link by the User pips.
The curve crosses the $y$-axis at $x=0$, i.e. $y=-2$ and it crosses the $x$-axis, known as the roots of the quadratic (polynomial) equation at $y=0$, i.e. $x=\sqrt3 -1$ and at $-1-\sqrt3$.