# Reciprocal Graph - Inverse function

Tags: solution-verification, inverse, inverse-function

f maps x from (0, positive infinity) to the set of positive real numbers, by $f(x)= 1/x.$ Does the inverse function exist ?

It is injective I believe, so I need to check for surjectivity too. This means the codomain must equal the range. I would say yes because the positive real numbers don't include zero, but the solution says the inverse function doesn't exist as the function is not "onto".

Does this mean they are saying 0 is included in the set of positive real numbers ? Thanks.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4515138/977780).

Comment: The range of $f$ is $(0, \infty) $ . $a\in(0, \infty) $ the preimage of $a$ is $\frac{1}{a}$ as $f(\frac{1}{a}) =a$

Comment: @SouravGhosh So am i correct then ?

Comment: Yes. See the above link for conformation.